# Laravel 5 Undefined variable in view error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view, undefined

I am new to laravel 5.4. I am not able to find a solution to this problem anywhere.

what I am returning `$items` filtered it gives me an error.

Controller

```
public function data()
{
    $items = registerdetails::all();
    return view('traineeattendance.details', compact('items'));
}
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Trainee ID</label>
    input type="text" name="trainee_id" class="form-control" value=" <td>{{ $item->trainee_id }}</td>">
</div>`
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `$items` would be an array. You need to check and use accordingly.

Comment: i dont know how to use it so that is why i asked it?

Comment: Just use like this: `@foreach ($items as $item)
    <div>{{ $item->FIELD_NAME }}</div>
@endforeach`

Comment: No sir i just want to called it in that form`s values field.please see the forms value field

Comment: i mean here input type="text" name="trainee_id" class="form-control" value=" <td>{{ $item->trainee_id }}</td>">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow this code:

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Trainee ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="trainee_id" class="form-control" value="{{ $item->trainee_id }}">
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: so that it gives error called Undefined variable: items (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Attendance_Management\resources\views\traineeattendance\attendance.blade.php)

Comment: yes i saw ,i changed it but still the same error sir.

Comment: replace return view('traineeattendance.details', compact('items')); to  return view('traineeattendance.details', ['items' => $items]);  and run this command in your terminal php artisan cache:clear and php artisan view:clear

Comment: make sure, are you using this variable in traineeattendance->details.blade.php  page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146353/discussion-between-mf-hossen-and-dasun).

Answer (score 1):

Since `$items` is a collection, you need to iterate over it:

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
    <div>{{ $item->trainee_id }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: how can i called it into above form value attribute?

Comment: i mean here input type="text" name="trainee_id" class="form-control" value=" <td>{{ $item->trainee_id }}</td>">

Comment: `<input type="text" name="trainee_id" class="form-control" value="{{ $item->trainee_id }}">`

Comment: @Dasun it's impossible if you're using controller method you've shown. Check routes file and make sure you're using correct controller method.